# Facebook iframe app with fullscreen popup?

Tags: facebook, iframe

With a Facebook iframe canvas app, is there any way to launch a modal pop-up (such as when clicking to magnify a photo, similar to http://fancybox.net/) that extends outside the bounds of the iframe's width? I'm thinking there would have to be some sort of communication with the _parent, but I'm not sure what's allowed or how to approach this.

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't.
Your application lives within an iframe within Facebook.  You can't alter Facebook's code outside the frame (against their policy).

You can pop up a new browser window in full screen, if you'd like.  But I'd question that as far as user experience goes.